# Post process depending on input sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm looking for a way to post-process the output of my pipeline given some input.

The scenario is that I'm predicting the value of items in various currencies, I have scaled these prices to USD (pre-processed) to make it easier to work with. Now, original currency is included as a feature in my pipeline, it is 1-hot-encoded in this case.

Now, my pipeline spits out USD prices, I'd like to have a post-processing step, that somehow has access to the original feature values (in this case only the currency), so that i can look it up and convert it back.

example pipeline:

```
make_pipeline(
    FeatureTransformer(),
    Regressor(),
    ConvertCurrency() # how do I figure out the currency here?
)
```

Comment: What does `Regressor` do? It changes the feature matrix or predicts the output? If it is predicting the output, scikit-learn's `make_pipeline` will not support that.

Comment: If you can figure out  the function which converts the original targets to dollars and then an inverse function for converting them back to original currencies, then you can use the [TransformedTargetRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html)

Comment: @VivekKumar the `Regressor` predicts the output.

Comment: Knowing the function is not really the problem, the problem is figuring out what the current "virtual" currency is and multiply the correct exchange rate with that currency